# Improve win2d lines animation UWP

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, line, win2d

I created an audio spectrum of frequencies and for the animation of the lines I used CanvasAnimatedControl but, the animation of the lines goes shots.

Code of Draw event:

```
    private void OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl 
        sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        double height = sender.Size.Height;
        double width = sender.Size.Width;

        for (int a = 0; a < nBands; a++)
        {
            _data.Add(new List<double>());
            for (int i = 0; i < DataPointsPerFrame; i++)
            {
                _lastValue = Math.Max(0d, Math.Min(1d, _lastValue + (list[a] * 0.00001)));
                _data[a].Add(list[a]);
            }
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < nBands; a++)
        {
            double total = 0;
            double range = 0;

            double widthBand = (width - 120 - ((nBands - 1) * 1)) / nBands;
            var padding = 60 + (a * widthBand) + (a * 1);
            for (int start = 0; start < _data[a].Count; start += ColumnAvgDataRange)
            {
                total = 0;
                range = Math.Min(ColumnAvgDataRange, _data[a].Count - start);

                for (int i = start; i < start + range; i++)
                {
                    total += _data[a][i];
                }
            }

            total = total * 0.0008;

            var point1 = new Vector2((float)padding, (float)height);
            var point2 = new Vector2((float)padding, (float)height - (float)(height * (total / range)));
            args.DrawingSession.DrawLine(point1, point2, Colors.Green, (float)widthBand);
        }
        canvasBands.Invalidate();
    }
```

I uploaded the project to this [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiONzWTtDqztgmnIkPwby_HHrT7W?e=h07sPg).

How can improve the animation of the lines to avoid having shots?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

```
    private void canvasBands_Update(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, 
        Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
    {
        double height = sender.Size.Height;
        double width = sender.Size.Width;

        point2 = new Vector2((float)padding, (float)height - (float)(height * (total / range)));
    }
```

I tried to modify as you said but I was not able to get a good result because with the update event it only changes once and returns only one point two. I uploaded the file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiONzWTtDqztgn33rLDbLNwgfayQ?e=ZE2RtC).
How can I change for the better?

Always thanks.

Comment: Our team member has replied the similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801784/single-line-animation-canvas-control-uwp), please check if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call invalidate on the canvas.
You need to separate your code:
You should update the geometry in the control's Update event handler and then just draw in the Draw event handler.

Here is an example that uses a random number generator to create the values.  You can adapt that to your uses.  Note that none of the calculation is happening in the Draw function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Test_One_Bar_UWP
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private List<double> _values = new List<double>();
        private List<Vector2> _points = new List<Vector2>();
        private Random _random = new Random();
        private float _barWidth = 30.0f;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void canvas_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
        {
            lock (_points)
            {
                double height = sender.Size.Height;

                foreach (var point in _points)
                {
                    args.DrawingSession.DrawLine(
                        point.X * _barWidth,
                        Convert.ToSingle(height),
                        point.X * _barWidth,
                        Convert.ToSingle(height) - point.Y,
                        Colors.Green, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        private void canvas_Update(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
        {
            _values.Add(_random.NextDouble());

            double width = sender.Size.Width;

            var lastPoints = _values.TakeLast(Convert.ToInt32(width / _barWidth));

            lock (_points)
            {
                _points.Clear();

                for (var i = 0; i < lastPoints.Count(); i++)
                {
                    _points.Add(new Vector2(i, Convert.ToSingle(sender.Size.Height * lastPoints.ElementAt(i))));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried without obtaining a good result I uploaded the new file thanks for the help.

Comment: You are thinking of the problem in the wrong way - as a retained mode graphic.  With the CanvasAnimatedControl you draw all of the bars, not just the latest one.  In your update function, you should generate an array of points and in the Draw function, you should draw lines between those points.

Comment: But if I create a matrix and then draw it with a for loop, you don't see the animation, this is my mistake ... couldn't you give me an example?

Comment: you don't need your own loop. The Update and Draw function will be called continuously at 60 times per second.  https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasAnimatedControl.htm

Comment: The best I can do at speed is [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiONzWTtDqztgwuSCiY2Ssg354K8) i can't understand i really need an example.

Comment: I updated my post with a sample of how to do updates.

Comment: I have tried to adapt your model to my problem and this is what I wrote. But there are always shots. How can I solve it? I uploaded the sample project [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiONzWTtDqztgwy4rh67ZzmNIO_Q) .