# Single Line Animation Canvas Control UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I have a line animation in this example, I have to get a one-line example. I tried modifying the code removing, for example, RemoveRange but I didn't get results. With Win2d Canvas Control.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas" Margin="5" Draw="Canvas_OnDraw" />
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
    private int ColumnAvgDataRange = 100;
    private float ColumnWidth => (float)(40 * ColumnAvgDataRange * 0.01);
    private int DataPointsPerFrame = 10;
    private readonly List<double> _data = new List<double>();
    private readonly Random _rand = new Random();
    private double _lastValue = 0.5;

    private void Canvas_OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataPointsPerFrame; i++)
        {
            var delta = _rand.NextDouble() * .1 - .05;
            _lastValue = Math.Max(0d, Math.Min(1d, _lastValue + delta));
            _data.Add(_lastValue);
        }

        if (_data.Count > (int)canvas.ActualWidth)
        {
            _data.RemoveRange(0, _data.Count - (int)canvas.ActualWidth);
        }

        args.DrawingSession.Clear(Colors.White);

        //var padding = .5 * (ColumnAvgDataRange - ColumnWidth);
        for (int start = 0; start < _data.Count; start += ColumnAvgDataRange)
        {
            double total = 0;
            var range = Math.Min(ColumnAvgDataRange, _data.Count - start);

            for (int i = start; i < start + range; i++)
            {
                total += _data[i];
            }

            args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle(start ,  (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (1 - total / range)), ColumnWidth, (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (total / range)), Colors.Green);
        }
        canvas.Invalidate();
    }
```

How can I reduce the example to one line? Possibly without using RemoveRange?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean about a one-line animation? Can you please show more details about your expected behavior?

Comment: I would like to reduce the example to a single line that oscillates on the y axis. so I would like to remove the part of code that creates other lines on the x axis. And you want the remaining line to swing on the y axis without shots.

Answer (score 0):

From this doc: [CanvasDrawingSession.FillRectangle Method](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_FillRectangle_2.htm) and your below code:

```
args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle(start ,  (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (1 - total / range)), ColumnWidth, (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (total / range)), Colors.Green);
```

We can know the width for one single line is `ColumnWidth`, then from the below definition:

```
private float ColumnWidth => (float)(40 * ColumnAvgDataRange * 0.01);
```

We can know that the `ColumnWidth` is 40, so in order to reduce your code to show only one line, the first method is to set the width of the `CanvasControl` to only contain one line, for example `Width=50` as following:

```
<canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas" Margin="5" Width="50" Draw="Canvas_OnDraw"/>
```

After that it should work fine.

The second method is to modify this code:

```
args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle(start ,  (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (1 - total / range)), ColumnWidth, (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (total / range)), Colors.Green);
```

From this `args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle` method, we can see the first parameter `start` is the X axis for the rectangle line, if we want to show only on rectangle line, we can only have one X axis, so please set a fixed value for X axis. For example: 1,2,3,4..., as long as this X axis is still inside the range of the `CanvasControl`, then any value is ok.

For example I set the 1 as the X axis as following:

```
args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle(1,  (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (1 - total / range)), ColumnWidth, (float)(canvas.ActualHeight * (total / range)), Colors.Green);
```

Hope it helps.